# What is the most performant way to create or delete many nodes in Drupal 7

Tags: php, drupal-7

I do the following in a for loop in order to create several nodes:

```
$node = new stdClass();
$node->type = 'myType';
node_object_prepare($node);
$node->uid = $myUserID;
$node->title = 'myTitle';
$node->field_myFieldf[LANGUAGE_NONE][0]['…'] = $…;
… some more values

node_save($node);
```

When profiling with XDebug, I can see there are way more PDO statement executions than expected, which I understand is due to the way nodes are persisted and in our case probably due to the many modules we use.

However, I wonder whether there is a better approach in Drupal 7 to create or delete several nodes at once, instead of one at a time.

The node's module method node_delete_multiple for instance seems to also generate individual DB deletes.

Answer (score 0):

[node_delete_multiple](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules%21node%21node.module/function/node_delete_multiple/7) - deletes multiple nodes.

to create multiple nodes this is the only approach as i see. foreach to go